# Software/Tool used in Stewart Calculus Book for 2D and 3D pictures

Tags: calculus, soft-question, math-software

I am curious to know which software/tool have been used in book

Calculus: Early Transcendentals
6th Edition by James Stewart

to draw 2D and 3D schematics of the book.

Thanking you in advance.[image][image][image]

Comment: Could you please provide a picture? Websites like [Math3D](https://www.math3d.org/) are a great resource.

Comment: In general, math books are written via [Latex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX), which has the capability of imbedding graphical images (i.e. jpeg files or *interactive* png files) directly into the document.  Assuming that Latex was used, which is by no means certain, it is therefore hard to predict which independent graphical package was used.  Complicating the matter, an independent graphical package might have been **avoided** by the use of Latex graphical **plug-ins**, such as PSTricks, PGF-Tikz, or Asymptote.

Comment: I have added few pictures now what is the opinion about tool or software.

Comment: Modern (free) math oriented graphics packages including Latex graphical plug-ins are amazingly sophisticated, capable of high-resolution imagery.  I (for one) can't predict the source of the images based on their quality.